# How do I create a customised auto-complete input in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap in a project for the first time, and there are a few things I haven't got to grips with yet.  Currently, I'm trying to create a search box which autocompletes with suggested items.

There are 2 in the example files - U.S. States and Countries - but I want to be able to set my own values in there (to be read in from the database each time). I had a look in the Bootstrap documentation, and this is listed (without any explanation) in the documentation for the previous release, but not mentioned or explained in the current docs.

I'm sure it must be possible to do, but don't know where to start! Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this Typeahead which is compatible with twitter bootstrap 3

https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead